# There is error in the transition of the slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I am trying to create the CSS slider, it's working well in auto play but when I willingly using the dots it's transition not working well. It takes hardly 5min to solve this if you already know. Please Help.
Or you have any other method to create the beautiful slider then let me know.

These are code given below, please see and run and see the error in transition.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("psr_slides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("psr_slider_dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.width = "0";
    slides[i].classList.add("trans");
    // slides[i].style.transform = "translateX(100vw)";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.width = "100vw";
  slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.remove("trans");
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

function autoInce(){
    for (let i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            plusSlides(1);
         }, i*5000);    
    }
}
autoInce();
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.psr_slider{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.psr_slider{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 60vw;
}
.psr_slide{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.psr_slide_1,.psr_slide_2,.psr_slide_3,.psr_slide_4{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 60vw;
    float: left;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.psr_slide_1{
    background: red;
}
.psr_slide_2{
    background: orange;
}
.psr_slide_3{
    background: pink;
}
.psr_slide_4{
    background: blue;
}
.psr_slider_right{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 1rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.psr_slider_right svg{
    height: 64px;
}
.psr_slider_left{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 1rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 100;
}

.psr_slider_dots{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 16px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.psr_slider_dot{
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #bbb;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: 1s;
}
.active{
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

.trans{
    animation: move 1s;
}

@keyframes move {
    0% { transform: translateX(0); }
    100% { transform: translateX(100vw); }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="psr_slider">
        <div class="psr_slide">
        <div class="psr_slides psr_slide_1"></div>
        <div class="psr_slides psr_slide_2"></div>
        <div class="psr_slides psr_slide_3"></div>
        <div class="psr_slides psr_slide_4"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="psr_slider_right" onclick="plusSlides(1)">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" fill="#fff" class="bi bi-chevron-right" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
              </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="psr_slider_left" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" fill="#fff" class="bi bi-chevron-left" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M11.354 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L5.707 8l5.647 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z"/>
              </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="psr_slider_dots">
            <div class="psr_slider_dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></div>
            <div class="psr_slider_dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></div>
            <div class="psr_slider_dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></div>
            <div class="psr_slider_dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For me, your code works. When I click on the dots, I go to the corresponding slide.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov if you click on dots fast than the transition goes wrong. Please try once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I'm answering my question myself. I get the answer now, where I'm wrong.
I used to transfer before using `width` property but now I use `transform` to transition. There is little bit change in CSS and JS code no change in HTML. Hopes that it helps you

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("psr_slides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("psr_slider_dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    var j = 100*i-(slideIndex-1)*100+"%";
    slides[i].style.transform = "translateX("+j+")";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

function autoInce(){
    for (let i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            plusSlides(1);
         }, i*5000);    
    }
}
autoInce();
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.psr_slider{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 40vw;
}
.psr_slide{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.psr_slide_1,.psr_slide_2,.psr_slide_3,.psr_slide_4{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 40vw;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    transition: all 1s;
}
.psr_slide_1{
    background: red;
}
.psr_slide_2{
    background: pink;
}
.psr_slide_3{
    background: yellow;
}
.psr_slide_4{
    background: green;
}
.psr_slider_right{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 1rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.psr_slider_right svg{
    height: 64px;
}
.psr_slider_left{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 1rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 100;
}

.psr_slider_dots{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 16px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.psr_slider_dot{
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #bbb;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: 1s;
}
.active{
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="psr_slider">
        <div class="psr_slide">
        <div class="psr_slides psr_slide_1"></div>
        <div class="psr_slides psr_slide_2"></div>
        <div class="psr_slides psr_slide_3"></div>
        <div class="psr_slides psr_slide_4"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="psr_slider_right" onclick="plusSlides(1)">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" fill="#fff" class="bi bi-chevron-right" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
              </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="psr_slider_left" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" fill="#fff" class="bi bi-chevron-left" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M11.354 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L5.707 8l5.647 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z"/>
              </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="psr_slider_dots">
            <div class="psr_slider_dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></div>
            <div class="psr_slider_dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></div>
            <div class="psr_slider_dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></div>
            <div class="psr_slider_dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```